# Unable to get values from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an ArrayList which takes an object.

`Handler.java`

```
public ArrayList<LinkedInAccountObject> getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase(){

    LinkedInAccountObject lao = new LinkedInAccountObject();
    counter++;
    lao.setAccountId(rs.getLong("account_id"));

    lao.setLinkedInAccountId(rs.getString("linkedin_account_id"));
    lao.setParentId(rs.getLong("parent_id"));
    lao.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));

    lao.setLinkedInAccountId(rs.getString("linkedin_account_id"));
    lao.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
    lao.setAccessToken(rs.getString("access_token"));
    lao.setExpiresOn(rs.getLong("expires_on"));

    laoarray.add(counter, lao);
}
```

My `PageLoader.java` uses this object to set values

```
ArrayList<LinkedInAccountObject> laoarray = lndb.getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase();

    for (LinkedInAccountObject lao : laoarray) {
    LinkedInPageObject lpo = new LinkedInPageObject();
    lpo.setCompanyID(lao.getParentId());
    lpo.setComment(lao.getComment());
    //lpo.setDescription(obj.getString("description"));
    //lpo.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
    }
```

But im unable to use the lao object to get the details, getting an null pointer.

when i print the lao object, it gives the result as below,

> array objects[null, LinkedInAccountObject [accountId=xxx,
>   parentId=xx, expiresOn=xxx]]

Comment: where does the `laoarray`in the `getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase()` method come from?

Comment: its a member of the function declared as  `ArrayList<LinkedInAccountObject> laoarray`

Comment: Try to check your counter object in getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase method while debugging.

Comment: Why are you bothering with a counter?  The whole point of using an `ArrayList` is that you can call `add`, over and over, without specifying a counter.

Comment: yes, i just used it for indexing.. but when i print my lao object it gives null in the result as specified

Comment: How are you printing the object, can you show that code?

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  Why didn't  you just write `laoarray.add(lao);` at the bottom of that method?

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm wondering that too. I'm assuming there is logic that wasn't included in the sample

Comment: where do you initialise the counter?

Comment: please find the two methods complete code...   http://pastebin.com/QZynWRXL    http://pastebin.com/nzwby52L

Comment: What do you think that line `counter=+1;` does?

Comment: we can leave that one.. i forgot to comment that line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you replace your loop in the second code with the following:

```
Iterator<LinkedInAccountObject> iterator = laoarray.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    LinkedInAccountObject lao = iterator.next()
    LinkedInPageObject lpo = new LinkedInPageObject();
    lpo.setCompanyID(lao.getParentId());
    lpo.setComment(lao.getComment());
    //remaining of your code.
}
```

**EDIT**

From all the comments that have been posted here I feel that you have initialised the `counter` variable as `0`. In your method `getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase()` you are looping through a loop using `rs.hasNext()`. Now if this is correct, Then when the first data is being stored, your method creates a new instance of `LinkedInAccountObject` in `lao`. Then it goes on to increment `counter` by `1`. So in this case `counter` was `0` now it becomes `1`.

After all your code that you uploaded being executed in the last line it executes `laoarray.add(counter, lao);`. Here counter being at 1 adds the `lao` object to the `laoarray` at position index 1, leaving position index 0 as `null`. Then it repeats till the end of the `ResultSet`. This means if your `rs` variable returned 10 rows, they would be added to `laoarray` in indices `1` to `10` with `0` index being null.

You could verify if this is happening or not by simply `System.out.println("laoarray length = "+laoarray.size());` in your 'PageLoader.java' after you have initialised the `laoarray` variable.

If this is correct then you could remove the `counter++;` in the method `getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase()` from its present location and set it after `laoarray.add(counter, lao);` as shown below:

```
LinkedInAccountObject lao = new LinkedInAccountObject();
//counter++; remove it from here.
lao.setAccountId(rs.getLong("account_id"));

lao.setLinkedInAccountId(rs.getString("linkedin_account_id"));
lao.setParentId(rs.getLong("parent_id"));
lao.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));

lao.setLinkedInAccountId(rs.getString("linkedin_account_id"));
lao.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
lao.setAccessToken(rs.getString("access_token"));
lao.setExpiresOn(rs.getLong("expires_on"));

laoarray.add(counter, lao);
counter++;//place it here
```

Comment: @user4771244 how are you actually initialising the `counter` variable in `getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase()`?

Comment: the arraylist first value was initialized with a null value explicit and so it returned null when the first object accessed vi the for loop.. once removing the initialization , it worked fine.. not using index using counters, i have set them in databases now :) ... thanks blip for your analysis :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Does you counter start at -1? You do counter++ before adding to the arraylist.
This would mean that the first entry is never filled.

You could edit the code to start at index 0, or in the for loop check if the lao isen't null before handeling it.

Comment: counter is at 0 and incremented

Comment: If your not using the index, you can also loose the complete counter... ArrayList add method works without an index, and adds the value to the end of the list (being the first element if the list is still empty)

Comment: If the counter = 0, and is increment before adding at index counter, this means your counter is effectively 1 when adding the first element, meaning index 0 is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't seem complete but my guess is that you modify counter before adding the item so if you have an array and start with counter = 0 you add the first element to position 1 and position 0 remains null.

Make it:

```
LinkedInAccountObject lao = new LinkedInAccountObject();
.... fill object values ......
laoarray.add(counter, lao);
counter++;
```

Comment: It is not an array, it is an ArrayList which is very different. The index isn't really relevant.

Comment: ArrayList is practically the same here. You add object to a position with add(counter,lao). Would be different if he just uses laoarray.add(lao) without specifying index

Comment: No, it isn't. The `ArrayList` only uses the index to determine where to insert the value. If the index is invalid you'd get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but the values will otherwise be added. This means looping over the values would not be affected by indices.